# Is there a way to use python in android applications programming?

Tags: python, java, android, android-studio, eye-tracking

I am working on an application that uses eye-tracking technology to detect eye movements..
what I want to ask, is there any way to use python to develop Android application? or integrate it with android studio?

and what is best language to develop an application with an eye tracking feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a few languages.
**Kotlin** - to create UI
**C++** - to create native lib
If you want to detect something you can use [tenderflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android)

Answer (score 0):

Try these platforms for Python Android Development:

1. QPython
2. PySide

It is possible to develop Android apps using Python, but won't recommend it as it won’t be as efficient as Android apps that are developed by using Java or Kotlin.

Comment: thank you, but it is because i need to add eye tracking features.. do you recommend another way to add it with android?

Comment: @ManalFathi You can use Google Vision API (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces#vision_face_detection-java) - it will help you detect human faces, I am not sure if it detects each eye movement but you can try it.
I also found an article on medium that shows details on how to implement the OpenCV library, 
Here is the medium post that you can follow: https://medium.com/@taolu_99738/developing-of-eye-tracking-application-for-smartphone-b875c50ee0c3 & also check this one 
https://hackernoon.com/make-an-eye-tracking-and-face-detection-app-as-a-beginner-d72e0139546b

Comment: i will check it and comeback, thank you